# Failed to build Move modules: "Unable to resolve packages for package 'my_first_package'"

Tags: move-lang, sui

New to move and sui.

I am trying to follow the documentation on Sui and attempted to use the command `sui move build` to build my move package.

I encountered this error:

```
Failed to build Move modules: "Unable to resolve packages for package 'my_first_package'".
```

Attached picture below shows:

1. my folder structure in local.
2. the content of the .toml file.
3. sui cloned locally pointing to `devnet` branch.

[image: attached picture]

Answer (score 4):

I solved my own problem, lol, by pointing Sui dependency correctly to `sui-framework/` on local.

Content of `.toml` file:

```ini
[package]
name = "my_first_package"
version = "0.0.1"

[dependencies]
Sui = { local = "../sui/crates/sui-framework/"}
# { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework", rev = "devnet" }

[addresses]
my_first_package =  "0x0"
sui =  "0x2"
```

Originally, retrieving from git was taking too long to build so it might be better to git clone sui to local and build relying on local.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you don't need to define 'sui' as a named address in the .toml file at all.

```ini
[package]
name = "MyModule"
version = "0.0.1"

[dependencies]
Sui = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework", rev = "devnet" }

[addresses]
my_module =  "0x0"
```

works just fine

Comment: I have the following `.toml`:

```toml
[package]
name = "my_first_package"
version = "0.0.1"

[dependencies]
Sui = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework", rev = "devnet" }
# { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework", rev = "devnet" }
# { local = "../sui/crates/sui-framework/"}

[addresses]
my_first_package =  "0x0"
# sui =  "0x2"
```
Gives an error though: ```
>sui move build
Failed to build Move modules: "Unable to resolve packages for package 'my_first_package'".
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I realized that the tutorial I was following was using deprecated location.

It went from:

```
Sui = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework", rev = "devnet" }
```

to

```
Sui = { git = "https://github.com/MystenLabs/sui.git", subdir = "crates/sui-framework/packages/sui-framework", rev = "framework/testnet" }
```

A more permanent solution would be to use `sui move new tmp_package` and then look at the auto generated `Move.toml` file.